# External FLASH chip controlled by an MCU: given the required capacity, how to select the page size?

Tags: microcontroller, flash-memories

I am selecting an external FLASH memory chip that I want to control (program/read/erase) from an MCU. For a given FLASH capacity, there are different options for the page size. I am wondering how to select this parameter?

I would appreciate it if you could share your opinions.

Comment: The page size does not matter, unless you do something where it matters. You might want to explain what do you want to do with the memory and why would the page size matter in your usage of the memory.

Comment: you want to make a decision based on facts, not opinions. How the page size might impact your system is wide and varied. For example if my microcontroller has only 8k ram and the flash page size is 4k and I might want to keep a copy of a page in ram, then I've just chewed up half my ram, so in this instance a smaller page size is preferable. As for my opinion, choose a part that has common features so you can drop in a similar part and not have to change your code. We're having to do this a lot in recent times as you have to use what you can actually buy.